# Azure Data Factory : Pipelines names missing in table when run in Debug

Tags: azure-data-factory

Scenario :

- Create a Pipeline in Azure Data Factory
- Run the pipeline **normally** with an "Add trigger --> Trigger now"
- Run the pipeline again in **Debug**
- Go to the page that shows all the pipelines that have been run or will be run. **(Monitor --> Pipeline runs)**
- It has two tabs : **"Triggered"** and **"Debug"**. Each of these tabs shows the pipelines you've just run in the previous steps.

**EXPECTED (CORRECT) :** In both tabs, the "Pipeline name" column is populated

**OBSERVED: (BAD) :** In the "Debug" tab, **the "Pipeline name" column is empty.** Everything is accurate expect the name is missing.

[image]

Comment: refreshed the page?

Comment: I have replicated this scenario and the behavior is as expected. This might be a bug from your end. Try creating a new data factory studio if possible and check again if possible.

Comment: After refreshing the page (Ctrl+F5), the issue was still there. Even after one hour. However the day after it was gone. Definitely a bug on Microsoft's end, maybe with some sort of temporary Debug container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an alternate browser - I experienced the same issue in Google Chrome, but the pipeline names did appear when I used Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I tried with another browser (randomly, Edge) and it worked. It might still have been a coincidence (just the fact that the other broswer had no cache yet) but I'm going to mark your answer as correct since @Pratik Lad did only write a comment

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Synapse Monitor, but the pipeline names are not showing in Edge.  I use FireFox and they're there.